# SASS pick random color from an array

Tags: arrays, random, sass

Is it possible, using SASS, to define an array of colors and then pick one at random and apply it to an element?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sass does not currently have a random function (see:  https://github.com/nex3/sass/pull/904).  Be aware that even if it did that the randomization only occurs during the compilation process to create a vanilla CSS file.

Comment: And since it happened only during compilation, there's no need for such a function. You need some JS here.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is now supported directly in Sass

Although its not supported directly in sass, you can use http://codepen.io to access the random() function in their Sass editor.

http://blog.codepen.io/2013/08/26/random-function-in-sass/
https://gist.github.com/chriseppstein/1561650

But as mentioned in the comments above, it only happens when you compile the CSS, but the CSS itself is still going to have only a static value out of your list

Comment: For anyone looking at this now, SASS now has a built in `random()` function. No need for workarounds.